# Regex not working in Android but works fine in Java

Tags: java, android, regex

I have the following code:

```
String compact =  Pattern.compile(" *(\\{) *| *(\\}) *").matcher(" { { } } ")
                     .replaceAll("$1$2");
```

In Java, `compact` contains `{{}}` - which is what I want - but on Android, I am getting `{null{nullnull}null}` which is making me crazy. Am I doing something wrong?

Following line produces the same result on Android:

```
String compact =  " { { } } ".replaceAll(" *(\\{) *| *(\\}) *", "$1$2")
```

Here is an [online Java version](http://regexr.com/3cd5g) for anyone who wants to play with it.

If it helps, I am compiling against Android SDK 23 with jdk1.7.0_79 on Mac in Android Studio.

**Update:** Using `"\\s*(\\{)\\s*|\\s*(\\})\\s*"` has same affect.

Comment: Maybe use \s for whitespace?

Comment: @cricket_007 Just tried, same result

Comment: @M-WaJeEh Did you get a chance to test this?

Comment: Does the issue persist?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I ended up using those patterns at compile time from build.gradle in Android Studio, which for my case was more efficient. I run that pattern once and save result in a file and use that result at runtime instead of running that pattern at runtime.

Comment: So yeah that pattern worked fine from `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why it behaves like that in Java, but I can tell you why it behaves like that in Android. I can give a few clues about Java though.

When you command a `Matcher#replaceAll(String)`, the class checks if there is a `find()`, and if it does have one, it replaces whatever was matched against in the input with that replacement `String` you provided.

So far so good.

However, when the replacement is actually a representation of a group, another route is taken. The class tries to find what corresponds to that group (see `Matcher#appendEvaluated(StringBuffer, String)`) and `append(String)` it to the internal `StringBuffer` that is used internally.

It does that by explicitly calling the method `group(int)`. The behavior of this method *both in Java and Android* is that it will return `null` if, when there's a match, there isn't one that corresponds to the group given. *Note: it throws exception when there is not a match at all and not just when it can't find one that corresponds to the group. Like `group(int)` without `find()`, for example.*

In the end, `StringBuffer` outputs the "null" `String` (literally the word “null”) when you append a `null` object. So, for every group you ask that isn't there, when there is a match, it will append the word “null” to it.

The algorithms used in Java are quite different and have a different output in that case of `replaceAll`.

Without testing too much or fixing inefficiencies (sorry, just browsing SO at 3 AM in december doesn't help me think straight), I think you could achieve, in Android, the same results as you would get by using what you were using in Java, by doing this instead of `replaceAll`:

```
String input = " { { } } ";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(" *(\\{) *| *(\\}) *").matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String a = matcher.group(1); // $1
    String b = matcher.group(2); // $2
    String replacement = null;
    if (a != null && b != null) {
        replacement = a + b;
    } else if (a != null) {
        replacement = a;
    } else if (b != null) {
        replacement = b;
    }
    if (replacement != null) {
        input = input.replace(matcher.group(), replacement);
    }
}
```

If it doesn't, please let me know. I only made some crude tests (it's 3 AM after all).

Comment: Of course, I assumed yesterday that you did *not* know enough about your input, as to avoid just appending a `replaceAll("null", "")` to the chain.